# How to rename a docker image from MiroK8S?

Tags: microk8s

I have imported a TAR file to a MicroK8S setup using this command :

`microk8s ctr images import my-service.tar`

After import, the image has an other name like : import-2021-09-08:1.0.1

Any idea on how to import to an other name or how to change the name after import ?

P.S. : The original name was : my-service:1.0.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution on the import command :

`microk8s ctr images import --base-name my-service my-service.tar`